# Dependencies between attributes of 2 and more classes

Tags: python, class, attributes, dependencies, self-reference

Is it possible to initialize instances of classes with attributes that are dependent across (not in circular way)?

Today, I use dictionaries instead of classes as follows:

```
dictA = {'A1': 10}
dictB = {'B1': 2}
dictB['B2'] = dictA['A1'] * dictB['B1']
dictA['A2'] = dictB['B2'] * 3  # dictA['A1'] * dictB['B1'] * 3

print(dictA)  # {'A1': 10, 'A2': 60}
print(dictB)  # {'B1': 2, 'B2': 20}
```

When I try to express the above with classes, I end up with `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A1 = 10
        self.A2 = B().B2 * 3

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.B1 = 2
        self.B2 = self.B1 * A().A1
    
a = A()
b = B()
```

The dictionaries (classes) are separate because they represent different types of data (e.g. employees and time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the initializers non-circular. Then you can use `@property` to lazily evaluate the properties

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A1 = 10

    @property
    def A2(self):
        return B().B2 * 3


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.B1 = 2

    @property
    def B2(self):
        return self.B1 * A().A1


a = A()
b = B()

print(a.A1, a.A2, b.B1, b.B2)
```

Result:

```
10 60 2 20
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! It seems with lazy evaluation, b.__dict__ does not return B2, but b.B2 works.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using the solution from this answer. The `@property` decorator is meant for simple functions which return some data which is already present in the class, without much computation/processing. The `A2` property creates an instance of `B`, to call a property of  `B`  which creates a new instance of `A`. A `@property` should not create multiple classes. Also, creating 2 classes to return 1 number is a very cumbersome approach.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A1 = 10
    def add_A2(self, x):
        self.A2 = x.B2 * 3

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.B1 = 2
    def add_B2(self, x):
        self.B2 = self.B1 * x.A1
    
a = A()
b = B()
b.add_B2(a)
a.add_A2(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a `RecursionError` because you create an instance of `B` to set `A2`, and to create an instance of `B` you need to create an instance of `A` to set `B2`. You will keep creating instances of `A` and `B` in a circular manner.

You can declare class attributes, which can be used without creating an instance of the class. Note that this value is always the same for all instances of a class. So you can use it for a value like `days_of_week = 7`, but not for a persons age `age = 34`, as a persons age is not always 34.

Assuming `A1` and `A2` can be class attributes, which are always the same, you could do the following:

```py
class A:
    A1 = 10
    def __init__(self):
        self.A2 = B.B1 * self.A1 * 3
    
class B:
    B1 = 2
    def __init__(self):
        self.B2 = self.B1 * A.A1
        
a = A()
b = B()
print(a.A1, a.A2)
print(b.B1, b.B2)
```